# Difference between "climate" and "weather" please

Tags: nouns

As a native speaker of Spanish I am confused because we don't have two different words for these terms

Comment: According to Wikipedia you do: [Clima](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clima) vs [Tiempo atmosférico](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_atmosf%C3%A9rico)

Comment: @mplungan: your comment seems off-topic as it does not deal with the English language ;)

Comment: [Weather](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/weather) | [Climate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/climate)

Answer (score 2):

Climate is the weather for an area over a period of time.
The Spanish climate is usually warm and dry.
The British climate is usually wet and cold.
Weather describes the state of the atmosphere.
"The weather today is it will be wet and cold in the morning but the clouds will clear and by the afternoon it will be sunny and warm."
"The weather yesterday was wet and cold with high winds."
Climate can also refer to other more general situations such as
"We cannot justify spending that much money in the current economic climate."

Answer (score 1):

Climate is the word for long-term trends in weather in a region.

Weather is the immediate day-to-day temperature/precipitation.

eg. What's the weather forecast for this week?
What's the climate like in southern Spain?

Answer (score 1):

"Climate" refers to the overall weather situation over a year or years. You can speak of a moderate/tropical/subtropical/continental/arctic climate. "weather" refers to the special condition of a day/some days: Yesterday we had rainy weather. / Last weak the weather was rather cold.